# Processing large dataset in Snowflake and Java Cron job

Tags: java, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I have the following tables in snowflake,

- Users with 225,000 rows. Users has userid column
- User Purchase History with 225,000,000 rows. User Purchase History has userid, list of upc for each userid.
- Recommendations with 40 million rows. Recommendations has upc and recommendations for each upc.

I need to join the three tables and process (and save) the selected recommendations for each user in the java spring boot service layer.
What would be the most efficient way to process (and save)  this information, in the java spring boot service layer?

Comment: Where is the data being saved, and why must it be done in Spring Boot?

Comment: @cela, The data is being saved in sql server so it can be queried by the user interface. It needs to be done in spring boot because for each user we need to call multiple API's and make sql server database calls to get user profile information and then query the User Purchase History, Recommendations then group aggregate the information to generate the user recommendations. Would you have a recommendation or input on what could be done better?

Comment: Use search optimization service, define it on User Purchase History and Recommendations tables.  
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/search-optimization-service

Comment: why snowflake is tagged ?